# Cannot resolve the name '<sometype>' to a(n) 'type definition' component

Tags: jaxb, xsd, gradle

I have the following xsd schema definition

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="foo"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:reference="reference.bar"
    >

 <xs:import namespace="reference.bar" schemaLocation="bar.xsd"/>

 <xs:element name="Foo" type="Foo"/>
 <xs:complexType name="Foo">
        <xs:sequence>
               <xs:element name="Id" type="xs:long" />
               <xs:element name="items" type="reference:Items" />
        </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

when I do `gradle generateSources` task I get next error:
`[ERROR] src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'reference:Items' to a(n) 'type definition' component`

This schema definition and bar.xsd are located in the same folders. Why I get this error?

Comment: Since you've solved your problem, you should answer and accept your own question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was with path where proejct is located. Seems jaxb when generating sources takes absolute path to xsd files. My path contained special symbols such as `[` and `]`